# Git push upstream

Tags: git, github

I've tried looking for an answer for this but can't  find a straight answer.

I'm running the code below.

```
git fetch upstream  # get the latest copy from master / upstream
git merge upstream/master  # merge the downloaded copies and merge to your copy
git commit -am"test"  # commit your latest changes
git push origin master  # push to your fork
git push upstream  # push to master copy from where you forked your project - is this safe?
```

is it safe to push to upstream (`git push upstream`)? My main goal is to apply my changes from my fork to the main project. Or there's a better way? thanks

Answer (score 2):

It depends on wether you have the privileges to push. If you haven't, ask the owner of the upstream repository to pull from your fork.

Comment: thanks Olaf.. yes I do have privilege to push. so the answer is yes - pushing to upstream directly from my copy is safe?

Comment: If you have push rights, then you don't need to fork the project. You can use the Read/Write URL to clone the repo, commit, and just `git push`.

Comment: Git will merge your changes to upstream, so I don't see any problems.

Comment: Dan - the reason that I have to fork the project is I need to do something that doesn't need to be pull from the production - while allowing others

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged this question as GitHub, I assume you want to push your changes to your fork, then issue a pull request from GitHub's UI. Git doesn't have a command line option to issue pull requests.

You can read more at https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests

Comment: I'm trying to push the changes from my fork copy to the master copy of the project - in most cases this is named as "upstream".

Comment: Well, `git send-email` is the moral equivalent.  It's a shame github doesn't support it and turn them into pull requests from a temporary branch.